# In Next.js, when using next-translate i18n plugin with dynamic routes, it does not work with non-default locale

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next-translate

In Next.js, when using [`next-translate`](https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate) i18n plugin with dynamic routes, it does not work with non-default locale.

I have 2 locales. Arabic "ar" and English "en". The default locale is "ar".

When I access this URL for example: `domain.com/post/1` it appears as expected and shows the Arabic content.

On the other hand, when I try to access the English version of the same post through this URL: `domain.com/en/post/1` it doesn't appear and gives 404 (Not Found) error.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example representing how to generate dynamic paths for both default and non-default locales when using `text-translate` i18n internationalization plugin with dynamic routes in Next.js:

```
// File: lib/local-data.js

import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export async function getLocalJsonData(localJsonFilePath) {
    // Get the path of the json file
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), localJsonFilePath);

    // Read the json file
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");

    // Parse data as json
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(fileContent);

    return jsonData;
}
```

.

```
// File: pages/post/[postId].js

import { getLocalJsonData } from "@/lib/local-data";
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";

export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }) {
    // Reading local json data.
    // Supposing you store your data in a json file within the project
    const posts = await getLocalJsonData("/data/json/posts.json");

    // Generate dynamic paths for default and non-default locales.
    const paths = posts.flatMap((post) =>
        locales.map((locale) => ({
            params: { postId: String(post.id) },
            locale,
        }))
    );

    // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
    return { paths, fallback: false };
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    // Reading local json data.
    const posts = await getLocalJsonData("/data/json/posts.json");

    // Return the value of the first element that passes the given test.
    const postObject = posts.find((post) => {
        return String(post.id) === String(params.postId);
    });

    return { props: { postObject } };
}


export default function Post({ postObject }) {
    ({ t: translate, lang: currentLocale } = useTranslation());

    return (
        <>
            <h1>
                {currentLocale === "ar"
                    ? postObject.ar?.title
                    : postObject.en?.title}
            </h1>

            <div>
                {currentLocale === "ar"
                    ? postObject.ar?.content
                    : postObject.en?.content}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```